# How to search all value with same ID in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to search all values in `TEXT` for same `ID` to find whether it contains "A", and add a column to show the result. Could someone help me on this? Thank you!

```
ID  TEXT  HAVE A?
1   A     YES
1   B     YES
2   A     YES
3   B     NO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create boolean mask with `Series.eq` then `groupby` on `ID` and `transform` using `any`, finally use `np.where` to select values from `YES` or `NO` based on this mask:

```
m = df['TEXT'].eq('A').groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')
df['HAS A?'] = np.where(m, 'YES', 'NO')
```

---

```
   ID TEXT HAS A?
0   1    A    YES
1   1    B    YES
2   2    A    YES
3   3    B     NO
```